# Transfer large files beween Android device and an iPad mini

Tags: file-transfer, samsung-galaxy-tab-7.7

I have an iPad mini and a Galaxy Tab 7.7 tablet.

What is the easiest way to transfer several large files between an Android device and an iPad device?

Comment: If both support [Wifi-Direct](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-direct), that might be the best choice to connect them. Not knowing the iPad side, I don't know how the transfer itself could work.

Comment: Do you have Internet connectivity on both devices via either cell data or Wi-Fi?  If so, there are numerous 3rd-party applications available that can make it an easy task.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to a computer, it might be easier to connect the Galaxy Tab and iPad to it via USB, mount both for file access (not sure how this is done in Apple world, but most Android tablets and phones come with built-in features for accessing storage via USB,) copy the files off the source device, and then copy them to the target.

If you need to do this over wireless connection and have access to the Internet (either via cell data or Wi-Fi,) third-party apps might be an easier solution. For example [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) is free, available for both [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropbox/id327630330?mt=8), but has a 300MB file size [limit](https://www.dropbox.com/help/5/en). [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) is another alternative, with a free 5GB storage, apps on both operating systems, with file size limit of [10GB each](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603).  There are a myriad other similar services that are available on both platforms, but all of them require Internet connectivity, and usually an account.

For direct device-to-device transfers there are fewer choices.  [AirBlue](http://www.redmondpie.com/airblue-for-ios-5-iphone-ipod-touch-ipad/) uses bluetooth connectivity on both iOS and Android devices for file transfer.  Unfortunately it's only available for jailbroken iPhones via Cydia store.  [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KB6hDNRAVpU) is another walk-through for file copying over Wi-Fi, but this requires for both Android device to be rooted, and the iOS device to be jailbroken.  Instructions from [here](http://www.blogham.com/transfer-videos-from-android-to-ipad-without-using-cables.html) are a bit dated, but do not require any rooting or jailbreaking of your devices, just a few apps that are freely available on [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer) and [iTunes Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628?mt=8).

Comment: Using a computer as an intermediate repository is the best and fastest way. Transferring the files from Android is straightforward - connect and mount as a drive - copy contents to computer. Transferring the files from computer to iPad has to be done through iTunes as a sync process.

Answer (score 0):

**Sharable** is a free to use smartphone & tablet and computer application that brilliantly facilitates file sharing between multiple operating system types. Using this app, you can share files between phone/tablet running iOS and Android; file can be share amongst phone/tablet or to and from computer running Mac as well as Windows. You can install the app on each of your devices and view the connected ones in your app’s dashboard. The next step is simply to decide which files to share and have them transferred over wifi.

Remember that the devices you use for transfer should all be connected over the same local WI-FI network.

http://sharable.in/

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternative to the ones they mentioned is BUMP

BUMP is available for [IOS](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/bump/id305479724?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bumptech.bumpga&hl=en)

This app lets you share selected files by *bumping* your phones/tablets side by side. This requires both phones connected on the same wifi network. Can also share files on your computer by going to a url and bumping with the space bar.

If setup properly, it will be very convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), works for me

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use the [Fast File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.fastfiletransfer&hl=en) app from Google Play. It's really good, and you don't need Internet.