# How do I transfer my videos from my android phone to my apple IPhone

Tags: file-transfer

How do you transfer videos from my android phone to my apple iPad

Comment: try dropbox or maybe vlc if you cant use these applications then try iTools

Comment: What have you checked already? Please [try these](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[file-transfer]+ios). Especially useful maybe: [Transfer large files beween Android device and an iPad mini](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/40297/16575)

Answer (score 1):

I think they have the easy transfer app (Move to iOS) , it was uploaded by Apple itself for android user to easily move to Apple Devices.

You can find it on google play: [Move to iOS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apple.movetoios&hl=en)

Comment: other way is to backup your data on your photo backup using gmail. and install photos app on your ipad from where you can access all photos.